# Java background JFrame with a Jpanel arranging images in a grid

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, background-image

so I've been working on my program and I am having trouble getting setting up a JFrame with a background image of a network map and then setting a JPanel using a MigLayout **on top** of the JFrame which will allow me to place images in accordance to the network map. I have seen several different ways on how to set a background image and have tried using an example I found elsewhere on this site but it's not quite working. Also, I researched more on this and found that having a JPanel ontop of a JFrame may prevent the JFrame background image from being seen. I was hoping that someone could take a look at my code and let me know if that is the case.

Here is my class to set the background:

```
public class bwMonBackground extends JFrame {
    Image img;
    public bwMonBackground() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/pwopperer/workspace/BWmon/src/customer_vlans.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}

}
```

Here is my main:

```
public class bwMonBackgroundMain {

    public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            bwMonBackground frame = new bwMonBackground();
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,20));
            migLayout testing = new migLayout();
            frame.add(testing.createLayout());
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();

        }
}
```

EDIT: When I run it like this, I only get a JPanel with the 6 JLabels I added into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a little nit picky, but you should always call `super.paintComponent` unless you have a REALLY, REALLY good reason not to.

Also, you should provide `Graphics.drawImage` with a `ImageObserver` where possible.  Basically this means if the image processing is taking place in another thread, the ImageObserver will not notified of changes and updated automatically ;)

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}
```

When placing components onto your map, you need to make sure they a transparent (`JComponent.setOpaque(false)`).  This will allow the background to show through.

Obviously, you could choose some components to be opaque so they are more easily readable or provide `AlphaComposite`s to provide translucent effects.

**Additional Ideas**

I wouldn't override `JFrame` in this manner.  Frames have content panes, which are responsible for the core content.

Besides, from memory, `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent` method :P

I would instead override `JPanel` (or `JComponent`) and user there `paintComponent` method instead, then either add this panel to the frames content pane or set it as the content pane itself (`frame.setContentPane(...)` - just beware, you do this BEFORE adding any other components to the frame, as this will effectively remove them from the UI ;))

Comment: Thankyou, I called super.paintComponents and will update my code. Is there a tutorial or example you would recommend that demonstrates the usage of ImageObserver that you are recommending?

Comment: Really, you don't need to worry about it to much for what you are doing, it is implemented by `Component` and thus implemented by `JFrame` on you behalf ;)

Comment: @Pat if you're really desperate to see `ImageObserver` in action, you can take a look at http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/177666/imageobserver-and-animated-gifs#