# How can I add images as a JPanel background?

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel, border-layout

I would like to make four panels using different backgrounds, and merge them together using a `BorderLayout`. I used `JLabel`, but I can't add any component to a `JLabel`, therefore I need to make it as a background.

I've search some code but it only tell how to add a background in `JFrame`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LoginPanel extends JFrame{
private ImageIcon top = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/user/Desktop/top.png");
private ImageIcon mid = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/user/Desktop/mid.png");
private ImageIcon center = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/user/Desktop/center.png");
private ImageIcon bottom = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/user/Desktop/bottom.png");

public LoginPanel(){


    JPanel topp = new JPanel();
    topp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
    topp.add(new JLabel(top),BorderLayout.NORTH);


    JPanel centerp = new JPanel();
    centerp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
    centerp.add(new JLabel(mid),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    centerp.add(new JLabel(center),BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    topp.add(new JLabel(bottom),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    topp.add(centerp,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    add(topp);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginPanel frame = new LoginPanel();
    frame.setTitle("Test");
    frame.setSize(812, 640);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Related Example : [JComponent not showing with picture background](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230)

Answer (score 3):

I would make a new class called `JImagePanel`, and then use that:

```
class JImagePanel extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public BufferedImage image;

    public JImagePanel(BufferedImage image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // scale image
        BufferedImage before = image;
        int w = before.getWidth();
        int h = before.getHeight();
        BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.scale(2.0, 2.0);
        AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        after = scaleOp.filter(before, after);

        // center image and draw
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int x = (getWidth() - 1 - image.getWidth(this)) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - 1 - image.getHeight(this)) / 2;
        g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Though the idea is good, +1 for that, still I would prefer to make two changes in this case. 1.) Since I am using an image as a background, hence I would override the [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()) method, so that the `JComponent` will attain the size of the image. 2.) The Access Specifier for `paintComponent(...)` method will remain `protected` instead of `public` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Check out

- [Add image to panel not using swings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774913/add-image-to-panel-not-using-swings/13775921#13775921)
- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [Java background JFrame with a Jpanel arranging images in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856027/java-background-jframe-with-a-jpanel-arranging-images-in-a-grid/11856562#11856562)